# Android Gradle several modules :transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug task fail

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

Not so long ago I wrote a library for my app which contains two modules: samples and the library itself.

As always, library module is included in samples module's build.gradle, though they're both on the same level in the hierarchy, just after the root:

```
----root
    ---samples
    ---tinyarbrowser
```

After the first release I used project without problems for about few weeks.

Last night I tried to build & run it before minor update. So... the whole night is spent trying to figure it out.

The main problem is:

```
:samples:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':samples:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
        D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17, 
        D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18, 
        D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\debug\0, 
        D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar
//...
```

It happens each time when I hopefully try to clean-build project with minor changes, none of which helps at the moment.

Current gradle files look as follows:

Root **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.2.30'
    ext.ankoVersion = '0.10.2'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
    minSdkVersion = 15
    targetSdkVersion = compileSdkVersion

    supportLibVersion = '27.0.2'

    supportDependencies = [
            design           :         "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}",
            appCompat        :         "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}",
    ]

    versionCode = 13
    versionName = '1.3'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Sample's **`samples`** module **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'project-report'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kkaun.tinyarbrowser"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    //Including project lib module here
    api (project(':tinyarbrowser')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v4'
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jre8'
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.anko', module: 'anko'
    }

    implementation ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlinVersion"
}


//tasks.whenTaskAdded {task ->
//    if(task.name.contains("transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug")) {
//        task.enabled = false
//    }
//}
```

And lib **`tinyarbrowser`** module **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
group = 'com.github.kkaun'
version = rootProject.ext.versionName

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.ext.versionName

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation supportDependencies.design
    implementation supportDependencies.appCompat

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlinVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$ankoVersion"
}
```

As I'm currently stuck with samples module, here is **`samples` dependency tree** output, lightweighted as more as possible:

```
+--- project :tinyarbrowser
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2
|    |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.3
|    |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.3
|    |              \--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.30
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.30
     |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.2.30
          \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.30 (*)
```

---

### **What I tried:**

- Clean-build it with dozens of exclusions and minor transitive dependencies
  changes;
- Invalidate cache / restart / clean local cache files;
- `implementation` vs `api` vs `compile`;
- Multidex for tiny lib?:) Tried just to be sure, all the same;
- Downgrade build version from 3.1 to 3.0 (D8 vs DX compiler): in that case i received `UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define` even with all dependencies except vital Kotlin removed;
- See one more below:

Actually I'm 90% sure that's about Kotlin as its components are widely used in both modules and it's the last thing I cannot
afford myself to be without, therefore I tried to exclude everything from samples module except Kotlin std's.
So I also tried this "dirty trick":

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded {task ->
    if(task.name.contains("transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug")) {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}
```

And yep, with that build actually finishes, but then I face another problem each time trying to run it on Xiaomi Redmi 4X:

```
Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: 
Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.kkaun.tinyarbrowser-1: Package /data/app/com.kkaun.tinyarbrowser-1/base.apk code is missing.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
```

As for this issue, I tried to disable/re-enable Instant Run, turn off MIUI-specific dev features, reboot etc. - it's still the same.

Out of options, for real. However, changing project structure for single lib module to be functioning is not an option at the moment.

Any constructive thoughts will be appreciated.

### EDIT:

Full stack trace of the key issue provided below:

```
> Task :samples:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':samples:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\AndroidStudioPr
ojects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrows
er\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\debug\0, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':samples:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while mer
ging dex archives: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18,
 D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\debug\0, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar
        at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\Androi
dStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\Ti
nyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\debug\0, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:225)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermed
iates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\e
xternalLibsDexMerger\debug\0, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:397)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:221)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\
debug\17, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\debug\0
, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17, D:\AndroidStudioPr
ojects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\TinyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\debug\0, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\T
inyARBrowser\samples\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:124)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:109)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:36)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:76)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:88)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:107)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:77)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:58)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:67)
        ... 5 more

BUILD FAILED in 35s
```

Comment: Can you provide whole stacktrace?

Comment: @dewarder, sure, just edited the question.

Comment: i guess you need to add `multiDexEnabled true` to **build.gradle** if this won't work try to delete and reinstall .gradle folder

Comment: @Raguel, As mentioned in the answer, I've already tried these options. By the way, what means "reinstall .gradle folder"? If it means regenerate all .gradle contents with clean/rebuild, I've already tried this.

Comment: @kkaun there is root folder where gradle files are stored, by default it is in home directory and it's name is _.gradle_, it is hidden by the way. I had same issues with DexArchive  the reason was, as i understand is conflict between dependencies. So i deleted _.gradle_ folder and clicked rebuild, it downloaded all gradle files again and DexArchive error disappeared.

Comment: @Raguel, just ot be sure, do you mean generated .gradle folder **inside** the root of the project, or some other one, stored somewhere on the hard drive in user directories?

Comment: @kkaun To get path to your _.gradle_ folder follow File > Settings... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > and here is that _.gradle_ folder's location

Comment: @Raguel, yep, tried to delete the exact package you've mentioned, not working, but thanks.

Comment: @kkaun I did have exactly same issue with almost identical configuration. I don't remember exactly how I fixed it, but I think it was something related to dependency changes. Can you try to downgrade/upgrade your support version to something like "26.x.x" and "27.1.1"?

Comment: @hluhovskyi, sorry for late reply, but i honeslty believe that's not about support versioning but Kotlin versioning/bugs. But yep, i tried to change support versions to "26.x.x" and higher till the last. Took 3-days break, trying to fix it again for now.

Comment: have a look at here. Does it help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46606139/gradle-error-transformdexarchivewithdexmergerfordebug-when-running-application

Comment: @xingjiu It's definitely not multidex issue, cause I've got the same issue with configured multidex.

Comment: @kkaun, have you tried building this with android build tools 3.0 instead (i.e., the com.android.tools.build:gradle line in your build file)?  As you might know, newer versions of the build tool use the D8 compiler, and 3.0 and below use the old DX compiler.  It's possible that you're running into a bug with D8.  Even if this isn't the cause, DX might give you a more informative error message to help diagnose it further.  More info about the DX -> D8 change here - https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/android-studio-switching-to-d8-dexer.html

Comment: @DaveLeeds, i'm aware of build tools 3.0 vs 3.1 versioning difference. Surely I tried 3.0 instead of 3.1. All that I got was `UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define //...` on the same gradle task. Regarding this issue and its references on SO the problem seems quite clear at first. But mine specific issue involves the fact that trying to optimize transitive dependencies I removed EVERYTHING except vital Kotlin JDKs in both modules and still got the same exception.

Comment: Edited question for providing info related to the last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this project, the build tools end up creating two different `BuildConfig.java` files - one in the `samples` module and one in the `tinyarbrowser` module. They both have the same package of `com.kkaun.tinyarbrowser`.  Because they're both in the same package, the build tools fail during merge.

The `AndroidManifest.xml` file in each of these modules dictates where the corresponding `BuildConfig` class will go, so we need to change the package in one of the modules so that they won't collide.

For example, you can update the manifest file in the samples directory from this:

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="com.kkaun.tinyarbrowser">
```

to this:

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="com.kkaun.tinyarbrowser.samples">
```

This also means that you'll need to shuffle a few classes around.  The classes in the `samples` module that are currently under `com.kkaun.tinyarbrowser` will need to move into `com.kkaun.tinyarbrowser.samples`.

Also, references to resources would also need to move. So for example, if you're doing this:

```
import com.kkaun.tinyarbrowser.R
```

Then it'd need to get updated to this

```
import com.kkaun.tinyarbrowser.samples.R
```

There could be a few other small references that would need to be updated, but this should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Well, i'm ALMOST sure that this answer pushed me in the right direction. I refactored code just few minutes ago, but there's always the "but" :) The appcompat is not importing in samples's classses. That's weird, because all the other dependencies work just fine. Trying to solve it for now.

Comment: Of course, by appcompat I mean inner module (own) dependency. The weirdest moment is that dependency tree shows me that appcompat is already resolved for samples module... Tried to invalidate cache etc., nothing works for now on

Comment: Well, after deleting .gradle and .idea i finally found that all builds well :) So in my case it definitely worked! Thanks!